# Anaconda ipython qtconsole launcher

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, qtconsole

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 with kde 5.6.4. I have installed anaconda python 3.5 which includes **ipython qtconsole**.

To launch ipython qtconsole, I have to type `ipython qtconsole` in terminal. Is there anyway I can create a launcher for it?

I know there a package, but it doesn't link to the anaconda python 3.5 and I don't want another separate python 3.5.

```
abhishek ~ $ apt-cache search ipython3-qtconsole
ipython3 - enhanced interactive Python 3 shell
ipython3-qtconsole - enhanced interactive Python 3 shell - Qt console
```

Comment: @JacquesGaudin No.

Comment: Sorry I meant this: http://linuxguidelinux.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/kde4howtocreatelauncherapplication.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating [a Desktop file](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Desktop_File), with an absolute path to the required `ipython`, such as:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/anaconda/bin/ipython qtconsole %u
Name=Jupyter Console
GenericName=Qt Application
Comment=Run a new IPython QT Console
Categories=Qt;KDE;
# MimeType=application/x-your-mime-type;
# Icon=some-icon
# X-DocPath=yourapp/index.html
# Terminal=false
```

Save this text file in `~/.local/share/applications/ipython_qtconsole.desktop`, and then drag the `.desktop` file into your launcher.

I am only guessing the location of your ipython is `/anaconda/bin/ipython`; to determine the correct path, run `which ipython` in terminal.